# Can't use Nexus Repository Manager 3.0 default admin user

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Just installed Nexus 3.0.0-03, started up, followed the doc, but can't login with default admin/admin123.

The only error I can see is the login refusal message:`Incorrect username or password, or no permission to use the application.`

Comment: Check your logs, it sounds like something is wrong with the install.

Comment: logs seems "normal", no error reporting in any case

Comment: Are you sure your keyboard is not switched to some other language or something like that? And if you're on Windows, did you install it to "program files" or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, everything is normal, except that I can't login. What would be interesting is to know how to create another admin from the configuration files.

Comment: @coolnodje I think my answer was right by higher vote. Could you choose my answer to right answer flag!

Answer (score 21):

user name is admin

There is password in **/nexus-data/admin.password** path in your nexus host.

`cat /nexus-data/admin.password`

you must change your password at first login

also If you implement nexus through docker, you should use command below:

`docker exec -it <container_name_or_ID> cat /nexus-data/admin.password`

Comment: Seems to be the `sonatype-work` folder, at least in 3.45.0 on Mac.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot create another admin user via configuration (without going deep down the rabbit hole), the initial user admin/admin123 should work.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem.

Steps I took to resolve it:

1. Open the admin.password file inside sonatype-work>nexus3 and copy it's contents.
2. Paste the copied value from step 1(from the admin.password file) into the password field. Enter 'admin' for the username.

Answer (score -1):

Look into location:

```
/home/[yourHomeDirName]/sonatype-work/nexus3/admin.password
```